# EF Core OnDelete Not Available

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have an issue in our system where a process is attempting to replace a record and it causes a FK Exception and fails. We are using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 2.2.2 in a .Net Standard 2.0 library. Most of the code was ported from an existing project that was not .Net Core.

I am trying to add cascade delete to the following model:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TermEntity>()
    .ToTable("Term", SchemaName)
    .HasKey(k => new { k.TermId, k.TenantId });
```

by adding the following:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<TermEntity>()
    .ToTable("Term", SchemaName)
    .HasKey(k => new { k.TermId, k.TenantId });
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

but I then get an error C1061 'KeyBuilder' does not contain a definition for OnDelete which makes sense as that is what is returned from HasKey and the OnDelete is on ReferenceCollectionBuilder. None of the methods used above return one of those and all of them (yes I have tried moving it around) give a similar error. The signature of the method this is in looks like:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

When I look up some EF Core tutorials I don't see the methods I am using and instead I see HasOne, WithMany etc usually with OnDelete at the end of the chain. I also thought I read that Cascade was the default so not sure why I have the issue in the first place if that is the case.

Can someone point me in the right direction to getting this fixed please.

The TermEntity looks like:

```
public class TermEntity
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the term identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The term identifier.
    /// </value>
    public short TermId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the Tenant identifier.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The Tenant range identifier.
    /// </value>
    public short TenantId { get; set; }

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets or sets the value.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>
    /// The value.
    /// </value>
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

NB: I was asked to provide the class I was using in the example and realised that I had posted the wrong one. TermEntity is the class I am having problems with.

Comment: Can you add TenantEntity structure?

Comment: Cascade delete is a behavior of a relationship. So where is your (failing) relationship? Can you show the FK Exception message?

Comment: From what I can see, you have no related entities with TermEntity, so Cascade cannot work  since there is no relationship

Comment: Yes sorry everybody I have just found that not all of the model was ported in an earlier task, only what was needed then. So I am now importing more models so that the relationship is there. Really sorry everybody but I am ok now and thanks for looking.

Comment: Just to confirm completing the model got me passed this issue so sorry and thank you once again.